# Как правильно поставить лого .SVG в html

Tags: html, css, svg

Как правильно поставить логотип в `.svg` формате.

На данный момент я ставлю его вот так:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 logo-inner">
    <div class="logo-store" >
        <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>">
            <img src="image/catalog/logo55.svg" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но оно не отображается. А если даже получиться, то все пропорции плывут.
Может как то кодом задать размер и пропорции `.SVG` ?

Вопросы почему `.SVG`? Да потому что он более достойно выглядит в мобильной версии сайта. И не мыльное лого.

Comment: Ваша разметка правильная. Только что проверил - на пустой странице ничего просто так не плывет. Более того, мне не удалось даже специально заставить плыть пропорции.

Возможно, у вас сама картинка изначально поплывшая?..

Answer (score 4):

**Способ №1** -  Используя тег object

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg">
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

---

**Способ №2** - используя тег embed

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg" />
```

---

**Способ №3** - используя iframe

```
<iframe src="image.svg">
  Ваш браузер не поддерживает SVG
</iframe>
```

---

**Способ №4** - с помощью CSS

```
#myelement {
  background-image: url(image.svg);
}
```

---

**Способо №5** - с помощью тега img

```
<img src="image.svg">
```

---

Поддерживаемые браузеры: ***IE9+, Chrome(все), Mozilla(все), Safari 3.0+, Android 3.0+*** Удачного кодинга...

Comment: У автора проблема с тэгом img - и вы ему советуете ... поставить тэг img?

Comment: Зачем переходить на личности? Я описал все возможные способы. У меня например тег img работает. У него нет. Или тег img нельзя использовать для svg. Можно ведь. Что вы на это скажете? Я вижу Вам делать нечего.

Comment: У автора проблема не с отображением картинок вообще, а с поддержанием правильного aspect ratio! Ценность вашего ответа - ноль.

Comment: Цель моего комментария - показать плюсующим серьезную проблему с ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставил лучше:

```
<svg>код картинки svg</svg>
```

Дальше можно в саму svg вставить нужные атрибуты, классы, а через viewbox изменить нужные размеры и т. д., все возможности внутри svg, а если вставлять через тот же backgroung или как img, управлять ей не выйдет.

Comment: А что значит код картинки ?

Comment: svg это и есть код, а то как вы видите ее в illustrator или sketch, это воспроизведение кода, суть в том, что вставляя svg через тег <svg> вы ставите как бы оригинал и можете дальше им управлять в любой желаемой форме, все остальные варианты не дадут такой возможности. Поизучайте что такое svg и как оно работает, там есть огромное поле для разбега. Если в двух словах, то внутри кода svg изображения доступна каждая "линия" для изменения цвета, размера, изменения состояния, доступна анимация и т. д., и т. д.

Comment: согласен наполовину - все, что можно сделать с SVG при инлайн добавлении в HTML, точно также возможно и при добавлении файла SVG через **object** @Pasha Dark недавно появилась у [Yoksel][http://css.yoksel.ru/a11y-for-logotypes/] интересная, очень подробная статья о добавлении лого на страничку.